# Negation of the definition of the Limit of sequence and proof with $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definition

I have a some trouble with proof, that $1$ is not a limit of sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \ \in \ \mathbb N$. ( I know that $\lim(\frac{1}{n})=0$ and I know how to prove it)

Definition of limit of sequence $(x_n)$ is: $\exists \ L \in \mathbb R$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \ N \in \mathbb N$, such that if $\forall \ n \geq N$, then $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$.

Now I want to negate it so:

$L \ \textbf{is not}$ a limit of sequence $(x_n)$: $\forall \ L \in \ \mathbb R$, $\exists \epsilon>0$, such that $\forall \ N \in \mathbb N \ \exists \ n \geq N$,such that $|x_n-L| 
\geq \epsilon$.

So now to my problem. I have from my negation, that it's true for all $L \ \in \mathbb R$ and for all $n \ \in \ \mathbb N$, therefore I can take $L=1$ and $n=1$, and I can find $\epsilon>0$, such that $|x_n-L| \geq \epsilon$, now consider:

$\Big \lvert \frac{1}{n}-1 \Big \rvert= \Big \lvert \frac{1-n}{n} \Big \rvert=\Big \lvert \frac{1-1}{n} \Big \rvert=\Big \lvert \frac{0}{n} \Big \rvert=|0|=0$ $< \epsilon$, but it's not true since $\epsilon>0$. What is the problem here? I got that 1 is a limit of my sequence. Isn't it? I hope somebody can explain me it. Thank you!

Comment: Your error is in how you chose n; your negation states that for all N, there exists n bigger than N which satsifies the rest. If it is for all natural N, then 1 will not be a suitable choice as it won't always be bigger than N

Comment: @BKosta first of all thank you for your answer. Honestly, I didn't understand, why my choice of n is false, if I did it with definition. Can u explain me it, please? I mean, if it's true for all $n \ \in \ \mathbb N$, then it's true for 1?

Comment: The statement, for all natural N, there exists n $>=$ N such that ... means that n will depend on N. If you have seen the epsilon-delta definition of limits elsewhere, then it is comparable to as treating N as epsilon and n as delta. Important point: it is not true for all n, it is true for all N. As a hint; notice that $| \frac{1}{n} - 1| >= \frac{1}{2}$ for all n bigger than 2.

Comment: @BKosta but if I take N = 1? Then it has to be true for n?

Comment: Yes it has to work for N = 1 but that does not necessarily mean n = 1. Remember, $n \geq N$

Comment: @BKosta you are right) I understood) thank you!